# Docker run vs docker service - automatic container restart

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

In many articles, video tutorials I've seen such explanation of one of *main* (so important that it warrant highlighting) points of difference between **docker run** and **docker service** commands: "That orchestration restarts your container if it stops". What exactly people mean when the say that about **docker service**? In case of docker run we have **--restart** flag. Isn't it the same thing? Where is the difference comming from?